# How to loop a button in Jquery

Tags: jquery

So I have this button

```html
<input type="button" value="change" id="change" onclick="go()" class="button">
```

and this function

```html
function go(){
  $("#theImage").attr("src", "heart.jpg");
};
```

and I also have another picture saved in the file root.

So when I press the button the picture changes to another picture, that part works, but when I press it again it does not change the picture to the next(or previous), how can I make it work?

Full Code:

```html
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>A Basic Form</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css" href="Template.css"> 

</style> 
</head> 
<body>
<input type="button" value="change" id="change" onclick="go()" class="button">

<img src="square.jpg" alt="square" id="theImage" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function go(){
  $("#theImage").attr("src", "heart.jpg");
};

 
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What is the next or previous image? All you are doing is telling that image to change to the heart.jpg. It will do nothing else.

Comment: its the square, but how can I make it work, like if I keep pressinng it will change every time

Comment: Do you just want to toggle between these two images or have you more images you want to add in?

Comment: Just the two for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this that will toggle the images:

```
function go(){
    var src = ($("#theImage").attr('src') === 'square.jpg') ? 'heart.jpg'  : 'square.jpg';
    $("#theImage").attr('src', src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already changed it to heart.jpg. Now if you want to set a kind of loop, use this javascript:

```
<script>
var i = 0;
var imgarray = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg' ...];

function go(){
        $("#theImage").attr("src", imgarray[i]);
        i++;
}

</script>
```

And

```
<input type="button" value="change" id="change" onclick="go()" class="button">
```

Comment: so i got this:

var i = 0;
var imgarray = ["square.jpg", "heart.jpg"];


function go(){
  $("#theImage").attr("src", imgarray[i]);
  i++;
};


But it does not seem to work?

Comment: The `i++` should be `i = (i + 1) % imgarray.length`

Comment: For some reason first time you press the button it does not change, but it does it on the second time

Comment: Change the order of the images in the array.